# DT in R - How to set caption color?

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, dt

Is it possible to set color in the caption of a DT table in an html document?

I've tried with

`datatable(table, 
      caption = paste0('<span style="color:#FF8700">Title one<span style="color:#000000">'),
      rownames=FALSE)`

but without results.

any idea?

Answer (score 9):

You can do in this way:

```
datatable(head(iris), 
          caption = htmltools::tags$caption("hello", style="color:red"),
          rownames=FALSE)
```

If you want to mix several styles:

```
datatable(head(iris), 
          caption = htmltools::tags$caption(htmltools::tags$span("hello", style="color:red;"), htmltools::tags$span("how are you", style="color:blue;")),
          rownames=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to pass a non-standard color into the caption ? #F2F3F4 ??

Comment: Indeed! I was leaving the ' in and it was not loading the css.

Comment: Hi @stephane laurent, what if I want to increase the size and also bold the caption?

Comment: @William CSS `font-size` and `font-weight`.